# can't both print and email from UIActivityController

Tags: ios, swift, dialog, share, uiactivitycontroller

I'm trying to share a ticket (my construct) to print and email using iOS UIActivityCoontroller. The ticket is formatted as both UISimpleTextPrintFormatter, and as attributed string. When the dialog is presented, I can get a choice to print, or to email, but not both. My code:

```
    let str = NSAttributedString(string: displayString, attributes: attrs)
    let ticket = [UISimpleTextPrintFormatter(attributedText: str)] 
    let ac = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: xxxxx, applicationActivities: nil)
```

When xxxxx = ticket, the the share dialog offers choices of Markup and Print.

When xxxxx = [str], the dialog offers email, message, AirDrop, Dropbox and others.

When xxxxx = [ticket, str] the dialog offers email, message, etc, but NOT print or Markup.

Shouldn't the third case include all the activities and present applicable data to each? What am I missing? (iOS 14.2.1)

Edit: to test this out, I created a new project, with one button linked to basically the code above. Same behavior observed. Individual resources when shared work as expected. (Text and print) when combined into one ActivityItem, the option to print does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the ticket variable is created as an array. It should not be. Removing the braces in the

```
Let ticket = [UISimpleTextFormatter ...
```

line gets everything working as expected.